# Echo category name in while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying my custom post type 'projects' in a while loop. But all the posts are in different category so I want to display the category name for each project but it does not output the category name.

Here is the loop:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()) {
                        $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <div>
                                <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url('home-project-thumb'); ?>" style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-height: 625px;">
                                <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/projectslider-<?php echo $color; ?>.svg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="projectslider-item">
                                    <div class="projectslider-content"><?php $categories = get_the_category(); $cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name; ?>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                                        <p <?php if ( is_page(95) ) { ?> style="color: white!important;" <?php } ?>><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p><br>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="projectslider-button projectslider-button-purple">Lees meer</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <?php } ?> <?php } } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I added following code in the loop:

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category(); $cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name; ?>
```

Comment: does your cpt support the default wp taxonomy "category"?

Comment: Get the post category if you have a custom post_type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#comment-977

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a custom taxonomy, you need `get_the_terms()`:

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category');
$term_name = $terms[0]->name;
```

Where `category` is the slug name of your custom taxonomy.

PS: if you're using the default WordPress `category`, `get_the_terms()` would also work (similar to above example).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be simply assigning the name to a variable, you need to 'echo' it as output:

```
<?php

$categories = get_the_category();

$cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;

echo $cat_name;

?>
```

Comment: Get_the_category only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use get_the_terms().